# Trouble with SPF-records sending to gmail-accounts

Tags: dns, email-validation, spf

I'm no SPF expert, meybe some of you are
Not so long ago, it began to be necesssary to authenticate in order to be able to send emails to the Google gmail-system.
At my company we run our own email-server(ns2.ourdomain.dk/x.x.x.69) - mostly for internal use.
So I set a SPF-record for the domain 'ourdomain.dk' in our dns like this

"v=spf1 a:ns2.ourdomain.dk ip4:x.x.x.69 ~all"

So now, we care allowed to send emails to gmail-addresses directly from this email server
After the email arrives at the receiver the detailed info about the email says:

Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of xxx@ourdomain.dk designates x.x.x.69 as permitted sender) client-ip=x.x.x.69;

Fine.
Now I would like to FORWARD emails from a web-server, ns3.ourdomain.dk at x.x.x.70, that runs on a different machine, using the internal mail-server, x.x.x.69 as a "smart-host".
Exim4 runs on that web-server and sends the email to the internal email-server, that forwards it to Google.
We have been doing this for years.
So i change the dns SPF text-record for 'ourdomain.dk'to

"v=spf1 a:ns2.ourdomain.dk a:ns3.ourdomain.dk ip4:x.x.x.69 ip4:x.x.x.70 ~all"

But now we get
Received-SPF: none (google.com: ns3.ourdomain.dk does not designate permitted sender hosts) client-ip=x.x.x.69;

Although the host ns3.ourdomain.dk SHOULD be allowed to send...
Has any of you experience with thus stuff?

Hans Otto

Comment: I recommend testing with this: https://kitterman.com/spf/validate.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `Return-Path` header of your forwarded email. It likely resembles `Return-Path: <user@ns3.ourdomain.dk>`. This causes Gmail to search for the SPF record at ns3.ourdomain.dk rather than directly at ourdomain.dk.

To resolve this, you have two options: add an SPF record to ns3.ourdomain.dk, or, better yet, configure Exim to use ourdomain.dk as the return path.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. This is more or less, what I have concluded from staring at the email-headers. Google somehow interprests ns3.ourdomain.dk as a domain, but it really is a host. And how should they know...?
We have to tighten up our game. I'll look into what is the easyest/best - either the dns-solution or the Exim-one.  At least we are in agreement on where the problem comes from.